# Summing a 2D array by "group"

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I have an array in the form

```
[
['16-24', 192081],
['16-24', 94452],
['16-24', 1055],
['25-34', 192081],
['25-34', 94452],
['25-34', 1055],
...
]
```

I have many items in the array that I'd like to reduce down to the unique left-hand entries. This is an example of what I'd like to reduce down to

```
[
['16-24', 287588],
['25-34', 287588],
...
]
```

Obviously the numbers here are a contrived example. I've looked into JavaScript's array reduce, but how can I use it to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reduce()` to sum and `map()` to change it to the format you want.

```js
var vals = [
['16-24', 192081],
['16-24', 94452],
['16-24', 1055],
['25-34', 192081],
['25-34', 94452],
['25-34', 1055]
];

var temp = vals.reduce(function (obj, cur) {
    var total = obj[cur[0]] || 0;
    obj[cur[0]] = total + cur[1];
    return obj;
}, {} );

var result = Object.keys(temp).map( function (key) { return [key, temp[key]]; });
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach which calculates the sums "in-place", avoiding the necessity of having to create a separate object with reduce etc., then converting the object back into an array.

The basic plan is to add to the first occurrence of each key the numbers from subsequent occurrences, then filter out those subsequent occurrences.

```
function sum(a) {
  return a.filter(([key, num], idx) => {
    var first = a.findIndex(([key2]) => key === key2);
    if (first === idx) return true;
    a[first][1] += num;
  });
}
```

For each tuple, we use `findIndex` to find the first tuple with the same key. By comparing that index with the current index, we can tell if the current tuple is the first occurrence. If it is, we leave it alone (`return true;`); otherwise, we filter it out, but first add its value to the first occurrence. This avoids the necessity of having to create an object with `reduce` etc., then converting the object back into an array.

The possibly unfamiliar syntax `([key, num], idx)` is [function parameter destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Pulling_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter). It takes the first parameter, assumes it's an array, and assigns the first element to `key` and the second element to `num`. This is a bit cleaner than referring to `a[0]` and `a[1]` from within the code.